# Redmine LDAPS Authentication

Tags: ldap, login, redmine

I'm setting up Redmine's LDAP authentication and am running into some odd issues.  I have the configuration setup and saved, and when I click on "Test" in the Authentication modes menu in Redmine for that configuration, it says "Successful connection".  I have also setup a user with the username stored on the LDAP host, and specified to authenticate using the configured LDAP authentication.

However, when I try to login as that user, it always fails.  It's almost as if it can't quite contact the LDAP server properly (even though the test succeeded).  I'm curious as to what that test actually does, and if there's a way I can look at some sort of log somewhere (nothing is really showing much) to show what/why it's failing.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: The directory server keeps a log file that may contain the answers you seek. If I'm not mistaken, OpenLDAP by default logs to syslogd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a simple problem with the username being incorrect.  Changing it to the correct one fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some applications (Redmine, [Kwok](http://www.kwoksys.com/), ...) can integrate with LDAP but it requires the users to exist in its database. Take a look at [this](http://www.redmine.org/issues/1838). I modify the `import.php` script to synchronize OpenLDAP users to MySQL database:

The `users` tables:

```
mysql> desc users;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| login             | varchar(30)  | YES  |     |         |                | 
| hashed_password   | varchar(40)  | YES  |     |         |                | 
| firstname         | varchar(30)  | YES  |     |         |                | 
| lastname          | varchar(30)  | YES  |     |         |                | 
| mail              | varchar(60)  | YES  |     |         |                | 
| admin             | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                | 
| status            | int(11)      | YES  |     | 1       |                | 
| last_login_on     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| language          | varchar(5)   | YES  |     |         |                | 
| auth_source_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| created_on        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| updated_on        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| type              | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| identity_url      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| mail_notification | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                | 
| salt              | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My OpenLDAP schema:

```
dn: cn=quanta,ou=x,dc=x,dc=x
cn: quanta
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
mail: x@y.z
givenName: a
initials: b
sn: c
userPassword: {SSHA}123
```

So, I import as belows:

```
"INSERT INTO users (login, firstname, lastname, mail, mail_notification, \
   admin, status, language, auth_source_id, created_on, type) \
    VALUES('" . $data[$i]["cn"][0] . "','" . $data[$i]["givenname"][0] . "',\
        '" . $data[$i]["sn"][0]." ".$data[$i]["initials"][0] . "',\
            '" . $data[$i]["mail"][0] . "',false,false,1,'en','1',\
                '".date('Y-m-d H:m:s')."','User')";
```

I also setup a [incron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/) job to do it automatically whenever an user is inserted or updated to the OpenLDAP:

```
/var/lib/ldap/*.bdb IN_MODIFY,IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/import.php
```